# Use one piece of data for two rows without writing it twice- MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I apologise about the title, I'm not sure how to word it.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name      |     Document     |     Notes
Company A |    Doc A Part 1  |   Withdrawn in Jan 2016
----------|------------------|------------------------
Company A |    Doc A Part 2  |   Withdrawn in Jan 2016
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Name      |     Document     |     Notes
Company A |    Doc A Part 1  |   
----------|------------------| Withdrawn in Jan 2016
Company A |    Doc A Part 2  |
```

Is there any way I can combine the 'Notes' field for those two rows so that they contain the same value; rather than writing out the note twice. The 'Notes' description will actually be much longer which is why I'd like to combine it. I know you can do this in excel; but I'm not sure if you can in access.

Also, if I do this, will I be denormalizing my data? Will I run into any complications; I just want both rows for that specific column to contain the same value without writing it twice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an index for Notes and reference to another Table.

But Combine two cells into one like in Excel, i don't know how this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a report where you for that textbox set property  *Hide duplicates* to *True*.

Comment: This is probably as close to an answer as I'll achieve. Guess I've bumped into one of MS Access' limitations. My final output is a report so as long as it works there I guess that will do fine. Thanks